# loyalty vs non loyalty customers customer count and sales SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables one is the **transaction detail table** which looks like below:

```
TXN_DATE    INDIVIDUAL_ID   TRANSACTION_NUMBER  ITEM_NUM    SLS    ACT_TRANSACTION_ID
1/2/2019          1               12345           326       $10     123366777
1/2/2019          1               12345           112       $20     123366777
1/2/2019          1               12345           554       $30     123366777 
2/3/2019          1               35565           144       $40     655544444 
2/3/2019          1               35565           585       $20     655544444 
4/3/2019          4               88567           987       $20     656697778 
4/3/2019          4               88567           788       $15     656697778 
5/3/2019          4               22456           659       $10     366655544 
5/3/2019          4               22456           781       $60     366655544 
1/23/2019         5               89464           364       $40     647778777
1/23/2019         5               89464           564       $30     647778777
4/3/2019          6               32224           891       $20     987779899   
4/3/2019          6               32224           345       $30     987779899
```

The other one is the transactions table which looks like below:

```
TXN_DATE    INDIVIDUAL_ID   TRANSACTION_NUMBER  SLS Loyalty_Number    ACT_TRANSACTION_ID
1/2/2019         1                12345         $60     987654     123366777
2/3/2019         1                35565         $60     null       655544444
4/3/2019         4                88567         $35     234456     656697778
5/3/2019         4                22456         $70     null       366655544
1/23/2019        5                89464         $70     655498     647778777
4/3/2019         6                32224         $50     556645     987779899
```

There is a 3rd table Loyalty, so if a customer is a loyalty member then he will be in the below table.

```
INDIVIDUAL_ID   Loyalty_number  
1                 987654            
4                 234456            
5                 655498           
6                 556645
```

I am trying to find the count of customers and their sales for loyalty vs non loyalty status. Below is the query which I am using:

```
SELECT GROUPS,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Customer_ID) COUNT_OF_CUSTOMERS,
    SUM(DOLLAR_VALUE_US) DOLLAR_VALUE_US,
    SUM(COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS) COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS

    FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
             Customer_ID,
             CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT LOYALTY) = 1 THEN 'ONLY' || ' ' || MAX(LOYALTY)
             ELSE 'CROSS'
             END AS GROUPS,
             SUM (DOLLAR_VALUE_US)             DOLLAR_VALUE_US,
             COUNT (DISTINCT TRANSACTION_NUMBER) COUNT_OF_TRANSACTIONS ---ADDED DISTINCT
        FROM (SELECT A.Customer_ID,
              CASE WHEN CARD_NUMBER IS NULL THEN 'NONLOYALTYTXN'
              WHEN CARD_NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN 'LOYALTYTXN' END AS LOYALTY,
                     DOLLAR_VALUE_US,
                     TXN_DATE,
                     A.TRANSACTION_NUMBER

                FROM transaction_detail A JOIN transaction B ON A.ACT_TRANSACTION_ID = B.ACT_TRANSACTION_ID)
       WHERE TRUNC (TXN_DATE) BETWEEN '01-JAN-19' AND '31-DEC-19'
       AND Customer_ID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Customer_ID)

    GROUP BY GROUPS;
```

By using this query I get three buckets:
1) onlyloyalty
2) onlynonloyalty
3) cross

Is there a way to just find loyalty and non loyalty numbers? because there are also cases when the customer might have not given their loyalty number at the time of checkout (example customer 1 and 4). I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Comment: And how do you define "loyalty"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff its just a flag, in another loyalty table, if that individual is present in the loyalty table then he is a loyalty member. In the loyalty table, the loyalty_id is same as the card number in the transaction detail table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have edited the question, please let me know if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I speculate that loyalty is related to having a card, which suggests:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN t.Card_Number IS NOT NULL THEN 'Loyal' ELSE 'Disloyal'
        END) as grp,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.individual_id) as num_customers,
       SUM(sls) as sales
FROM transaction t
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN t.Card_Number IS NOT NULL THEN 'Loyal' ELSE 'Disloyal'
          END)
```

Comment: wondering how efficient this solution would be since you're using `case` in `group by`. Can you comment on that? I am guessing the execution plan would be the same as my query above.

Comment: @django-unchained . . . This looks much simpler to me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the second table for this:

```
select 
count(distinct(INDIVIDUAL_ID)),
sum(case when Card_Number is null then SLS else 0 end) as non_loyalty_sum,
sum(case when Card_Number is not null then SLS else 0 end) as loyalty_sum
from transactions;
```

Comment: this is not clear to me, where did you get the transactions2 table ?

Comment: @Somya I just wanted to emphasize that you need to use second table only which is transactions